# JSON, node.js: access classes via its name (String)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Here's my situation, I have a JSON that looks somewhat like this:

```
{
    "items": [{
            "type": "condition",
            "data": {
                "type": "comparison",
                "value1": {
                    "source": "MyType1",
                    "component": "Attribute1"
                },
                "value2": {
                    "source": "MyType2",
                    "component": "Attribute2"
                },
                "operator": "gt"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "then",
            "data": {
                "result": "failed",
                "message": "value1 is too high"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and would want it to translate to:

```
if (MyType1.Attribute1 > MyType2.Attribute2) {
    result = "failed";
    console.log("value1 is too high");
}
```

Now my problem is, I don't know how I would translate the entries of `value1` and `value2` to actual code, or rather, how I could access the Object `MyType1`(maybe through something like `getAttribute("MyType1")`).
Since I am going to have a whole bunch of sources which each have different components, I cant really write a huge dictionary. Or I would like to avoid it.

The goal is to allow creating `if - then - statements` via some interactive UI, and I figured it'd be best to save that code as `.json` files. (Think rule management system).

So, TL,DR, How would I access a Class Attribute `this.MyType`, if I only have a String **MyType** to go from? And how would I access the value `this.MyType.MyValue`, if I get another String **MyValue**?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
I'd really like to avoid using eval, for obvious reasons. And if I have to - I guess I would need to create Dictionaries for possible JSON Values, to validate the input?

Comment: Is this the syntax you're looking for? `this["MyType"]["MyValue"]`

Comment: @NicholasTower Need to be careful in which context and where the keyword "this" is used.

Comment: @adriani6: You're right. I'm just mirroring what they were using: `this.MyType.MyValue`

Comment: @NicholasTower Yes, this is exactly it! I didnt know that you could access the attributes of "this" directly via bracket notation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of parser. At first we need some way to store variables and maybe flags:

```
const variables = {};
var in = false;
```

Then we go through the code and execute it:

```
for(const command of items){
  switch( command.type ){
   case "condition":
     //...
   case "then":
    //...
  }
}
```

To access a variable we can simply do

```
var current = variables[ identifier ];
```

To store its the other way round:

```
variables[ identifier ] = current;
```